# Java: Throwing exception inside the catch block

Tags: java, exception

Lets say I have a method `combine`

```
T[] combine(T[] arr1, T[] arr2, Comparator<T> cmp, Class<?> type) throws IllegalArgumentException{

...

}
```

And inside that I want to create an array using reflection. `T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, arr1.length+arr2.length);`. If an error accors during initializing `newArray` I want to throw `new IllegalArgumentExeption()`.

How should I do this preferably? Can I do this with try and catch blocks? Inside the try block I would try to initialize the array and inside the catch I would throw the IllegalArgumentEception.

Comment: Did you try implementing it in a Try.. Catch.. ?  You'd have to specific the exception you want to return though, that IllegalArgumentException otherwise I think you'd get the generic exception.

Comment: I'm curious, why ask this question? Why did you not try throwing an exception from a catch block to see if it works? It would have answered your question, and probably quicker than just asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as you suppose but I would be careful about two points :

- catching any exception and not a specific exception
- throwing the `IllegalArgumentException` by wrapping the caught exception. Having the full stracktrace may help to debug

For example :

```
try{
...
}
catch (Exception e){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception during combine() invocation with params..." , e);
}
```

Note that declaring `throws IllegalArgumentException` in the method declaration is really not required as the client doesn't have any constraint to handle it : it is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).
It is like declaring `throws NullPointerException` for a method that can throw it.
If you want to constraint clients to handle the exception, use rather a checked [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).